# Is there any way to calculate ffmpeg output dimensions other than rendering out a frame?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

So say I have:

`ffmpeg -i input in.mp4 -vf scale=iw*0.2:ih*0.2 out.mp4`

Or any filter where the output dimensions are changed.

Is there some way to retrieve the output dimensions from ffmpeg after the filter stack is applied other than just rendering out an output frame and measuring it, without calculating it independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [null muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#null) to output no file, but it will still show the output dimensions.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=iw*0.2:ih*0.2 -frames:v 1 -f null -
```

In the console output you'll see something like:

```
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 64x48 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
```

Where in this example 64x48 is the output width x height.